# masscan grep into a text file

Tags: bash, grep

I want this command:

```
masscan -p80 192.0.0.0/16 | grep -oE '[0-9.]{7,15}'
```

Which greps "live" pure IPs to drop those IPs into a text file.

Any idea how to get into file things that are happening on screen?

Comment: `masscan -p80 192.0.0.0/16 | grep -oE '[0-9.]{7,15}'>scan.log `

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Requests for tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Problems with using the command line are more ontopic for https://superuser.com . Good luck.